# What is the best way or tool to show how long a command line operation takes?

Tags: windows, command-line, time

I want to know how long a command takes to run. At the moment I am doing this:

```
echo | time | find "current" & dowahdiddy.exe & echo | time | find "current"
```

Which shows me the time before and after:

```
The current time is: 11:39:14.38
...dowahdiddy output...
The current time is: 11:39:15.44
```

I have to determine the difference. I could probably write a simple command line executor that shows me how long a shell operation takes, but I'm sure there are a bunch of ways to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [TimeThis](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=913795CD-7026-4143-AE85-1F5E096F9BE0&displaylang=en)

From the microsoft download page...

> Times how long it takes to execute a
>   given command.

You should already have this command installed if you have installed the windows resource kit. This command should also work on the later versions of windows even if the download page says "Windows 2000 resource kit."

Comment: Thanks, now I can see just how slow my TFS checkouts are. Crippling, but accurate. :)